# Is there a way that I can upgrade PDI jobs and transformations via script from version 6 to 9

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi, spoon

Is there a way that I can upgrade PDI jobs and transformations via script or editor from version 6 to 9. I am working on more than 300 transformations and it will be difficult to open each and every one of them and then use save as option to upgrade them to a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you leave them as created with Pentaho 6, and then run tests to ensure everything works and only open the jobs/transformation that aren't working in Pentaho 9 to see where the incompatibilities lay?

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which [a comment should be used instead of an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173)). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."